# Shp is not valid or recognized data source, QGIS 3.10

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

I worked on this layer last night, and today I can't open it. This layer was linked to an excel spreadsheet. And perhaps even more interesting, I duplicated this layer and stylized it into a different theme. This layer was stored on external flash drive.

I will upload this layer:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/zr7cmcpxgdu3ype/GB.rar/file

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your attribute table (.dbf) has some strange contents. It looks like somehow it was corrupted by your link to microsoft.

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw the same. What to do?

Answer (score 11):

[Shapefile Technical Description](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) shows how a shapefile's header is structured (Page 4). If you open any SHP file in a [Hex Editor](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com), you'll see that first 24 bytes of the header should be `00 00 27 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, but yours is `32 91 52 41 80 C3 3C BE 17 E8 58 41 5E 92 CF 09 41 91 52 41 EF 44 41 43`.

Briefly, your SHP file is, I guess, irreversibly corrupted. It's not related QGIS. As @Kartograaf states, your DBF file has strange contents, too.

Somehow your flash drive might be corrupted. If so, there are many reasons of that. I'm not sure if it would help but I suggest you to try to use fixing tools for USB.

Comment: I think it is not possible to repair layer. But I still dont know what was happend, how I do it?

Comment: Somehow your flash drive might be corrupted. If so, there are many reasons of that. I'm not sure if it would help but I suggest you to try to fix tools for USB.

Comment: Yes, you are right, only one folder was locked, but I resolved that, but I didnt sucseed. Thank you guys.